# Cookies in reponse header not showing in browser

Tags: laravel, vue.js, cookies

So I have a webapp with a vue2 frontend and a laravel (5.8) backend. With some requests I receive cookies from the backend like this:

```
        Cookie::queue('cookiename', 'content', 120 , '', '',config('myconfig.force_https_cookies'), true);
```

Locally on my computer everything works as expected. The cookies are being sent with the response and then show up in the firefox/safari web-developer tools. When I deploy the app on my server the cookies are still correctly being sent with the response header but they won't show up in the developer tools or anywhere else. Even typing document.cookie in the console won't reveal them.

Now the weird thing is. At some point my frontend should send a request to the server with these cookies and this is also working. So actually everything works as expected but the cookies somehow remain insivible client-side.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

1. You have last argument (`httpOnly`) set to true.

`HttpOnly` means that cookies will visible only trough http requests and not visible in js. You should set it to false, if you want to work with them in js.

2. Check `secure` argument.

If you don't have ssl and have `secure` argument set to `true`, it may cause the problem.

Try to set it to `false`.

3. `path` and `domain` arguments have default value = `null`.

Try to change values of path and domain arguments from `''` to `null`.

P.S. I used `forever()` method because the IDE shows its accepted arguments. Never mind.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. It's true that I have HttpOnly set to true because I actually don't want javascript to be able to access it. But the cookie should still be showing up in the developer tools as it does in the local environment. Also the column "HttpOnly true/false" in the developer tools otherwise would not really make sense.

I use an SSL connection and changing the path/domain does not help.

Comment: @felidae Did you try to set secure to false?

Comment: Yeah I also tried to set the secure flag to false, no help. :(